# MRZ / Passport Reading in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, ocr

I'm currently developing an app in React Native and I want to people able to read passport data with NFC. Now the NFC part isn't a must but would be cool, the most important part would be to read the MRZ area on the passport to extract the person's name, passport number, etc. Now, I am not really sure where to start so was looking for some recommendations for implementations. I've looked into OCR but not found a proper library yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to do that too but i can't find any library.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-passport-reader or use react-native-camera onTextRecognized method